# VALUE() For a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range, contains `01, 02, ... 12` in `Text` category format cell. (Column `A`)

And another contains `1, 2, 3, ... 12` in `General` category format cell. (Column `B`)

When I using this formula: `=(A1=B1)` returns **`FALSE`**, and Using: `=(VALUE(A1)=B1)` returns **`True`**

---

Here I need using **SUMIFS** as:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E, A:A, B1, ...)
```

Here the problem is in comparison between **Column `A`** values and **Column `B`** values.

How can I change the above formula as:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E, VALUE(A:A), B1, ...)
```

To returns the converted form of the `A:A` range in numeric?

Comment: can you please share some data so we all know what you're trying to do?

Comment: Strange ! SUMIFS should work even if the numbers are formatted as text.

Comment: Are your cells in E:E text or numbers?  Are you having multiple criteria where all the criteria are TRUE?  Sumifs is an AND condition not an OR condition.

Comment: @ForwardED, `E:E` Cells are numbers. The `A:A, B1` condition is not returns True, because `A:A` column numbers are stored as Text.(01, 02, ...) so I need change to Number first. but `VALUE` function is not working on a range as `VALUE(A:A)`. @ImranMalek, Right. The SUMIFS is works. But the problem is in criteria comparison. I need comparing `1`, with the (`01,02,...`) range, returns the corresponding `01` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it would be easier to convert the single criteria value from a true number to text-that-looks-like-a-number than converting an entire column of text to true numbers on the fly.

```
=sumifs(e:e, a:a, text(b1, "00"))
```